# Does 'yield' still agree with 'the subject' in 'measures can be undertaken that yield/s positive outcomes?

Tags: verb-agreement, extraposition

Good day, does 'yield' still agree with the 'subject' in the following sentence? The place of the modal verb 'can' is confusing.

> Some people contend that **measures** **can** be undertaken that **yields** positive outcomes

(Here the subject is 'measures' followed by modal verb 'can', and then, 'yields' is in singular form because  measures-can (subject-verb agreement) already agreed.

Or should it be

> Some people contend that **measures** can be undertaken that **yield** positive outcomes

(measures-yield) as (subject-verb)

Comment: Assuming @Clare has the gist of it right in terms of intended meaning, there remains a problem with *that*. You really, truly, deeply need to use *which* in this instance. "... *which* [will] yield positive outcomes." This will prevent the misparsing that produced Haseo's answer.

Comment: Using "which" would indeed prevent the misparsing, but it would also suggest that, whatever measures are undertaken, they would yield positive outcomes.  I think you really need "that", to make the relative clause restrictive, rather than merely additional information about all the measures that can be undertaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second one is correct:

> Some people contend that measures can be undertaken that **yield** positive outcomes.

*Yield* here agrees with *measures*.  There might be some confusion because the relative clause *that yield positive outcomes* does not come directly after the noun phrase that it modifies. If we place it directly after (adjacent to)  that noun phrase, we get

> Some people contend that measures that yield positive outcomes can be undertaken.

It should be clearer now that *yield* agrees with *measures*.

Relative clauses do not have to immediately follow the head noun that they modify. A relative clause that does not follow immediately the head noun is called an **extraposed relative clause**.

Cambridge University's *Language and Cognition*,
Volume  9, issue 2,
 contains an abstract of a study called  ['When relative clause extraposition is the right choice, it’s easier'](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/language-and-cognition/article/when-relative-clause-extraposition-is-the-right-choice-its-easier/069AC4A898E26596B4323EAA2B0E3179), and it  explains that

> speakers prefer [relative clause exposition] over adjacent ordering when the [relative clause] is long in relation to the [verb phrase], the subject [noun phrase] is indefinite, and the main verb is passive/presentative.

Let's check the clause which concerns us, which is

> measures can be undertaken that yield positive outcomes

1 is the relative clause long in relation to the verb phrase?

It is longer. The verb phrase is *can be undertaken*; the relative clause is *that yield positive outcomes*.

2 Is the subject indefinite?

Yes, *measures* is indefinite. We can't identify which measures are being referred to. Perhaps no definite measures are in the speaker's mind.

3 Is the main verb is passive/presentative?

It is the passive *can be undertaken*.

The same abstract contains another example of relative clause exposition:

> Some options were considered that allow for more flexibility.

Notice how similar in structure  it is to the one you ask about.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tip before answering: *use commas and semicolons, it will make the reading way easier, I had to read it twice in order to understand it.*

---

Yes, it must still agree with the verb; even though **That** is referring to the subject of the main clause **Measures**, which is plural, **That**, which is representing *Measures*, is still singular; therefore:

> *Some people contend that measures can be undertaken; that **yields** positive outcomes.*

The subject must always agree with the verb no matter what.

Comment: @Clare, if that is one relative clause, then, in fact, **yield** is correct; however, if it were a *relative clause*, it obligatorily would have to be placed as close to the noun it is describing as possible:

*Some people contend that measures that yield positive outcomes can be undertaken*

It makes no sense at all to place it at the end of the sentence, it is not a *dummy subject*, it is an *adjective*; if it is not placed close to the noun it describes, the sentence becomes completely ambiguous.

I do doubt that it was supposed to be a relative clause.

Comment: Now you see why it has to be placed as close to the noun as possible? - But of course, if you show me an example of this being officially used, maybe in a magazine, journalist article or etc... then I will consider such locomotion.

Comment: No matter how *far* 'that' is from 'measures', nothing in between is a noun, so the interpretation as a relative pronoun is valid -- and there was no semicolon or period to suggest a contextual demonstrative pronoun instead.  If it was demonstrative, it would be singular in this case; but the antecedent would not be 'measures', but the entire preceding clause.

Comment: @Phil Sweet, Seem like YIELD(only) is fine. Also, I intentionally used 'that' instead of 'which' for coherence. I undertand what you mean here, thx.